# How to install Norton Internet Security in my archos tablet?

Tags: anti-virus

I have purchased a Norton Internet Security where it's written in the box that this is good for computers and tablets both, with three licences. I  want to use one of the licences for my tablet, however, given that there is no disc player in my tablet, I guess I need to download NIS somewhere in the internet for my tablet and then add the password, am I right ?

Can anyone throw light on this please ?

Comment: what sort of tablet?

Comment: What operating system is the tablet running?